# several domains for one Facebook login

Tags: facebook-login

I'm trying develop Facebook Login in my App. 
In the App, each users registered, has a subdomain asociated like user1.myappdomain.com, user2.myappdomain.com...

But some users want another domain like www.otherdomain.com and next this is linked to subdomain. The otherdomain is in my VPS at same IP. But when I try to make login with facebook from otherdomain I retrieve an error, because www.otherdomain.com isn't myappdomain.com.

Is there a solution for that? I want to have only one facebook app for all domains.

Thanks!